# OptionCaption for a select with an optgroup tag

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am using this binding to create an opt group select box.

```html
<pre>
<select data-bind="disable: disableForm, foreach: List.available, value: List.selected">
    <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: category}, foreach: items , disable : items.length==0">
         <option data-bind="attr: {title: name}, text: name, value: id, enable: Active"></option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
</pre>
```

I am trying to use optionCaption, but it works with only with options tag, any way to achieve this functionality with optgroup ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [KnockoutJS - Binding value of select with optgroup and javascript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189660/knockoutjs-binding-value-of-select-with-optgroup-and-javascript-objects)

Comment: Can you please brief ?