# Use optgroup with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to manually render options inside of optgroups in knockout.js with guidance from Ryan Niemeyer's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189660/knockoutjs-binding-value-of-select-with-optgroup-and-javascript-objects).  It works fine, but only if the options are rendered immediately.  If they're loaded subsequently, then the correct item does not select.

The code and fiddle link are below.  Changing

```
t: ko.observable(null)
```

to

```
t: ko.observable(t)
```

makes it work, so the problem is definitely the delayed loading, and I have valueAllowUnset set to true.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/exyy7hq2/3/

HTML

```
<select data-bind="template: { name: 'selectTemplateType', data: t }, valueAllowUnset: true, value: selectedId"></select>
<div data-bind='text: selectedId'></div>

<script type="text/html" id="selectTemplateType">
    <!-- ko ifnot: $data -->
        <option>No template selected</option>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: $data -->
        <option>Select</option>
        <!-- ko foreach: groups -->
            <optgroup data-bind="attr: { 'label': name }, foreach: types">
                <option data-bind="option: id, text: name"></option>
            </optgroup>
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

JavaScript

```
ko.bindingHandlers.option = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
       var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
       ko.selectExtensions.writeValue(element, value);   
    }        
};

var t = {
    groups: [
        { name: 'a', types: [{id: 1, name: 't1'}] },
        { name: 'b', types: [{id: 102, name: 't2'}, {id: 103, name: 't3'}] },
        { name: 'c', types: [{id: 5, name: 'x'}] }
    ]
}
var vm = {
    t: ko.observable(null),
    selectedId: ko.observable(103)
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
setTimeout(function(){ vm.t(t); }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems if you're not using the options binding, Knockout simply has no way of adjusting things when you dynamically generate new options, even with `valueAllowUnset` set to true, so my approach simply won't work; the correct options need to be there when bound.  One decent way to achieve this is to render the `select` *only after* the values are present, like below (and also the option custom binding is not needed - just a regular value binding on the option element).

http://jsfiddle.net/exyy7hq2/11/

```
<!-- ko if: t -->
<select data-bind="template: { name: 'selectTemplateType', data: t }, value: selectedId"></select>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: t -->
<select>
    <option>No templates loaded</option>
</select>
<!-- /ko -->
<div data-bind='text: selectedId'></div>

<script type="text/html" id="selectTemplateType">
    <option>Select</option>
    <!-- ko foreach: groups -->
        <optgroup data-bind="attr: { 'label': name }, foreach: types">
            <option data-bind="value: id, text: name"></option>
        </optgroup>
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```